# Fail AOSP build in case of unresolved maven dependencies

Tags: android, bash, maven, makefile, android-source

In Android.mk file I have this code to download some packages via Maven. It uses pom.xml and other stuff, but this is not important in scope of the question.

```
ECHO_RESULT :=  $(shell mvn dependency:copy-dependencies -f $(PATH)/pom.xml -Dmdep.stripVersion=true -DoutputDirectory=$(OUT_PATH))
```

Android.mk pass a word to Maven and waiting while Maven resolving it's dependencies. It will proceed further even if Maven will fail to download something. Also, Maven doing it's work silently. So, here are questions:

1.How to fail android build in case of failed Maven dependencies?

2.How to log Maven output into terminal?